# How to load another View in DetailViewController in iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

How can I load a View from Nib file into DetailView for an iPad on a button click and back to previous view on another button click present in child view.

Answer (score 1):

I found this site useful:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009775

Answer (score 1):

The following code should steer you in the right direction.

To load a new ViewController:

```
- (IBAction)myBtnPushed{
NSLog(@"myBtnPushed");

NewRightVC *newRightVC = [[NewRightVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewRightVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[detailViewController.navigationController pushViewController:newRightVC animated:YES];

NewLeftVC *newLeftVC = [[NewLeftVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewLeftVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newLeftVC animated:YES];
}
```

To go back to the RootViewController and DefaultViewController in a UISplitViewController:

```
[detailViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

[Example Project to examine can be downloaded here.](http://www.mediafire.com/?49yb2n49cky9tzy)

[Example obtained from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263128/splitviewcontroller-with-two-navigationcontroller-linking-protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263128/splitviewcontroller-with-two-navigationcontroller-linking-protocols)