# splitViewController with Two NavigationController linking protocols

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

**EDIT: Added Source Project**

[--> I uploaded a sample project that clearly shows my dilemma which can be found here <--](http://www.mediafire.com/?49yb2n49cky9tzy)

I created a Split View-based Application. I then added a second UINavigationController to the DetailViewController inside the MainWindow.xib.

I then pop a new UIViewController Subclasses when a toolbar item is clicked. I use the following code to conduct the pop:

```
DocumentDetailVC *DetailViewController = [[DocumentDetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DocumentDetailVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[detailViewController.detailNavController pushViewController:DetailViewController animated:YES];

DocumentsVC *RRequestViewController = [[DocumentsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DocumentsVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:RRequestViewController animated:YES];
```

This works. The issue I am having is how do I pass information or function calls from the Main side of the Split View to the Detail side of the Split view?

If I present the UIViewController via the following method:

```
DocumentDetailVC *RRequestViewController = [[DocumentDetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DocumentDetailVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
RRequestViewController.delegate=self;
RRequestViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[RRequestViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentModalViewController:RRequestViewController animated:YES];
[RRequestViewController release];
RRequestViewController = nil;
```

I am able to complete a reach back through a protocol as intended.

DocumentDetailVC, when loaded via the pushViewController, the hierarchy is as follows:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self]); 
//self = <DocumentDetailVC: 0x4e0d960>
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.parentViewController]);
//self.parentViewController = <UINavigationController: 0x4e0ce30>
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.parentViewController.parentViewController]);
//self.parentViewController.parentViewController = <UISplitViewController: 0x4e0d0f0>
```

Thank you for your assistance. This problem is consuming my life!

[--> I uploaded a sample project that clearly shows my dilemma which can be found here <--](http://www.mediafire.com/?49yb2n49cky9tzy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I know am very late for answer but this answer is, I think, perfect and working. Try it. Open your RootViewController.h, on the top write this line:

```
#import "Left.h"
#import "Right.h"
```

in @interface RootViewController  write this lines

```
Left *lefty;
Right *righty;
```

after that declare property as,

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Left *lefty;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Right *righty;
```

go to ROOTVIEWCONTROLLER.M file synthesize as,

```
@synthesize lefty;
@synthesize righty;
```

after that in RootViewController.m just replace your function with this one

```
    - (IBAction)myBtnPushed{
    NSLog(@"myBtnPushed");


    lefty = [[Left alloc] initWithNibName:@"Left" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    righty = [[Right alloc] initWithNibName:@"Right" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    lefty.delegate=righty;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:lefty animated:YES];

    [detailViewController.navigationController pushViewController:righty animated:YES];


}
```

in delloac write this,

```
[lefty release];
lefty = nil;
[righty release];
righty = nil;
```

It's done, run your app. I tested, it's done.